# Quiero consultar una api desde localhost y me pone la del frontend como default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

estoy creando el frontend de una app en react y he querido consultar una api local desde el app.js pero al hacerlo me da por default el port del frontend

tengo la api en el puerto 4000

y el front en el 3000

si pongo con axios directamente la direccion de la api si me da el return
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he configuado la direccion de la api en una variable de entorno asi

`REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL= http://localhost:4000`

y este es el codigo del app.js

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import Pacientes from './components/Pacientes'
import nuevaCita from './components/NuevaCita'
import Cita from './components/Cita'
import clienteAxios from './config/axios'



function App() {
  // State de la app de

  const [citas, guardarCitas] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const consultarAPI = () =>{

      clienteAxios.get('/pacientes')
        .then(respuesta =>{
          console.log(respuesta)
        }).catch(error =>{console.error(error)})
    }
    consultarAPI()
  },[])
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route 
          exact path="/"
          component={Pacientes}
        />
        <Route 
          exact path="/nueva-cita"
          component={nuevaCita}
        />
        <Route 
          exact path="/cita/:id"
          component={Cita}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

y esta la configuracion del axios

````
const clienteAxios = axios.create({
    baseUrl:process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
})

export default clienteAxios;```
````

Comment: No entiendo, te refieres que en vez que se ponga el puerto 4000 se pone el 3000 por defecto?

Comment: Puedes compartir de que forma estas definiendo la variable de entorno? Usas un archivo `.env` o asignas la variable en la ejecucion del script?

Comment: Solo por validar... despues de cambiar el .env has reiniciado el servidor? los cambios en ese archivo solo se toman cuando inicias el servidor...

Comment: Tu error muestra que /pacientes no se encontro y eso es lo que esta en tu código no hay nada de /paciente en un route path por eso sale ese error.